# NAT64 embedded formats used by actual phone carriers

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, nat, ipv4

I'm refactoring some of my network code due to Apple's guidelines to support full IPv6 networks, and they state one reason for this is that carriers are starting to make the conversion.

When I test with Apple's NAT64 network, I see IPv4 addresses coming in mapped to IPv6 in the form:

```
64:ff9b::xxxx:yyyy
```

Based on the NAT64 spec, it seems there are other possibilities, but I am not sure if these are ever used.

I'm hoping that I can just assume the above format, but I would like to know what NAT64 mapping styles other phone carriers are using.

EDIT: I omitted an important detail from my original question - that I need to do some filtering based on IPv4 ranges in certain scenarios. So I need to be able to convert IPv6 to IPv4 for the addresses where that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. Don't assume anything. Query the DNS64 and use what you get. Everything else *will* break.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted an important detail from the question (I just edited it to add it), which is that I need to do this conversion in order to handle some business logic. So I need to add code to handle the conversion of any formats I might see.

Comment: What you want is impossible, you can never know all the possible formats, so adjust your business logic. Otherwise you will just be fooling yourself...

Comment: Right, but what formats should I adapt to? I need to know specific carriers that use different NAT64 formats from Apple's NAT64 and then run tests against those so I can see exactly how they work and verify them.

Comment: Again: you want something impossible. There is no way you can know and adapt to every NAT64 network now and in the future.